# Adjoint of right shift operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Define the right shift operator as $S: ℓ^2 \rightarrow ℓ^2, ||S||=1, S(x_1,x_2,...)=(0,x_1,x_2,...)$.

What is the adjoint $S^*$ and what are $SS^*$ and $S^*S$?

I know that $S^*$ is the left shift operator but how can I prove this? And what about the other two?

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481256/let-t-h-to-h-be-defined-by-te-n-e-n1-for-n-1-2-then-find-hi and many other similar questions.

Comment: As for the other two, the product of linear operators is just composition. To compute, say, $SS^*$, you take an arbitrary sequence $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$, apply $S^*$, then apply $S$. Left shift, i.e. $S^*$, produces $(x_2, x_3, \ldots)$, and right shifting this vector produces $(0, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$.